# Display plots based on tabPanel() selection in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below I have a `tabPanel()` with to subpanels. I want by default both plots to be displayed. Then if the user press `SUBTAB 1` only the left plot to be displayed. If he presses `SUBTAB 1` again both will be displayed again. The same logic for `SUBTAB 2` and right plot.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Explore Data"),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("tabPanel 1",
             tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel("SUBTAB 1",
                        fluidRow(
                          column(width = 6,
                                 plotOutput("Plot1", height = "350px") 
                          )
                        )
               ),
               
               tabPanel("SUBTAB 2",
                        fluidRow(
                          column(width = 6,
                                 plotOutput("Plot2", height = "350px") 
                          ) 
                        )
               )
             ) #Close inner tabsetPanel
    )
    
    
  ) #Close outer tabsetPanel
) #Close FluidPage

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(seq(0,10), seq(100, 110), col = "red")
  })
  
  output$Plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(seq(0,10), seq(0, 10)^2, type = "b")
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This would require some major hacking with the underlying `JavaScript` as `tabItems` are meant to hide their content whenever they are not selected. Possible, but why using such a non-standard behaviour? Maybe you want a `shinyWidgets::checkboxGroupButtons`?